# Automatically moving to BigDecimal when float is out of range

Tags: ruby, floating-point, biginteger

Huge `Float` numbers are not automatically converted to `BigDecimal` as with conversion from `Fixnum` to `Bignum`. For instance, `2.5**1000` generates `Infinity`. I can manually define a `BigDecimal` as `BigDecimal('2.5')**1000`, but this will slow down the computation when the numbers are not huge and `BigDecimal` is not required.

Is there any way to make the transition from `Float` to `BigDecimal` automatic (similar to the transition from `Fixnum` to `Bignum`)? Or is there any other Ruby class which does this? I don't care about the precision of the floating point numbers.

Answer (score 2):

As one possibility I see to monkeypatch the `Float` class. Since the overflow is likely to appear on arithmetic operations only, you probably need to overwrite five methods `:+`,`:-`, `:/`, `:*`, `:**` like that:

```
require 'bigdecimal'
class Float
  alias_method :__power, :** 
  def ** other
    result = self.__power other
    result.abs == Float::INFINITY ? BigDecimal(self, 0) ** other : result 
  end
end
puts 2.5 ** 1000
#⇒ 0.87.....E398
```

Not very elegant, but it does a trick.

Comment: Perhaps you can make it more elegant by using `prepend` module.

Comment: @sawa I thought about that, but I finally decided there is no reason to encapsulate the functionality into a module, since it nevertheless is not a “mixin,” it is a `Float` class patch only.

Comment: Thanks Mudasobwa! It worked, but now the computation time is much higher than when I define all variables in BigDecimal from the beginning. I guess that's because of the extra if-then-else (?:) in floating point operations.

Comment: And the second problem is that for integers, var=2**62 belongs to Bignum class, but if we set var-=1, then var belongs to Fixnum. Should I overwrite these classes for Bignum as well?

Comment: The `if` construct is nothing comparing to a time `BigDecimal` invocation is required. So, whether you have, say, ten constants, I would go with defining them as constants. `BigDecimal` is known to be slow, for evident reasons. And, yes, this patch affects instances of `Float`s only. Whether one wnats the same functionality on `Integer`s, `Integer` should be patched as well.